# Setting default values for columns in Hibernate during query mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, automapper, hibernate-mapping

```
@Column (name="AMOUNT")
private BigDecimal amount;
```

I saw many answers in Stackoverflow, the solution is either using `columnDefinition` or set the default value in Java contructor.

But what I need is for data query, not table creation or data insertion. When I use hibernate session to query out the object, and call the method `getAmount()`, it will return null `BigDecimal` Object, which I want to set the default value to 0 `BigDecimal`.

How can I do that since the mapping is done by Hibernate framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use a `@Transient` getter method.  In this case, you may want to mark the getter for the amount field as protected or private (Hibernate won't care) and then expose a special public method that is annotated with `@Transient` that performs the translation for you.
2. Use a `@PostLoad` annotated method event callback to translate the value rather than a `@Convert`.  You'd likely want to leverage part of #1 where you add a new property that stores the translated value you calculate in the post load callback and then annotate the field or getter with `@Transient`.
3. Use an attribute converter if you can leverage JPA 2.1.  In this case, you would annotate the field with `@Convert` and specify a converter class implementation that translates a null value to `0`.

The benefit of the first two options is that you don't need to be concerned with how to map values back to the database column (e.g. does `0` translate to a `NULL` at the table level).

From a performance perspective, if `amount` is accessed numerous times, I'd probably use #2 personally and cache the value after having translated it once.